# URLOpenBlockingStream

Tags: visual-c++

Can I use URLOpenBlockingStream on win32 console application ?

I have a simple code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <urlmon.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool url(){

LPCWSTR pfile(NULL);
HRESULT hRez = URLDownloadToFile( NULL, _T("www.google.com"), (pfile), 0, NULL );
if( hRez == 0 ){
return 1;
// download ok
}
else{

return 0;// download failed
}
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

cout<< url();
return 0;
}
```

and it returns compiler error

```
All outputs are up-to-date.
1>vvconsole.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _URLDownloadToFileW@20 referenced in      function "bool __cdecl url(void)" (?url@@YA_NXZ)
1>C:\Users\Prem kumar Sekaran\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\vvconsole\Debug\vvconsole.exe   : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>Build FAILED.
```

I am using built in libraries, Do I still need to link the .lib file ?

Comment: Is the project charset unicode or multibyte?

Comment: You're not using URLOpenBlockingStream in this code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`URLDownloadToFile()` requires the header `urlmon.h` and `urlmon.lib` library. Add below line to the top of your code to link this library.

```
#pragma comment(lib, "urlmon.lib")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <urlmon.h>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment(lib, "urlmon")
using namespace std;


bool url(){

LPCWSTR pfile(NULL);
HRESULT hRez = URLDownloadToFile( NULL, _T("www.google.com"), (pfile), 0, NULL );
if( hRez == 0 ){
return 1;
// download ok
}
else{

return 0;// download failed
}
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

cout<< url();
return 0;
}
```